# Manipulate the `this` object using a newly created Array.prototype method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, this, prototype

I am trying to extend the `Array` object in Javascript exactly like this. I am trying to manipulate the values of the array (present in the `this` object) using the prototype like in the function.

```
function clear() {
    this = [];
}
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'clear', { value: clear, enumerable: true, });
```

It is giving me a error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

I am aware that the `this` is immutable. What is the workaround? I am not looking to create a new Object that emulates the Array constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

```
this.splice(0, this.length)
```

I guess you can also do `this.length=0` directly, but it feels kinda hacky.